# Using substitute on a variable

Tags: vim

How would I go about completing the following function in vimscript?

```
fun! Foo()
    let l:bar = "Hello there, world!"
    # Perform a substitution on l:bar, changing "world" to "kitten"
endfun
```

That is, how do I perform a substitution on a variable, rather than the current buffer.

I know that in order to substitute on the buffer, I can write

```
silent :%s/world/kitten/g
```

but what is the equivalent command for substituting on a variable?

Comment: Re: rollback: Tags are for marking programming language, not the title.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

See `:help substitute` of `:help substitute()`.

It is the counterpart of the substitute command (See `:help :substitute`).

```
substitute({expr}, {pat}, {sub}, {flags})       *substitute()*

    The result is a String, which is a copy of {expr}, in which
    the first match of {pat} is replaced with {sub}.  This works
    like the ":substitute" command (without any flags).  But the
    matching with {pat} is always done like the 'magic' option is
    set and 'cpoptions' is empty (to make scripts portable).
    'ignorecase' is still relevant.  'smartcase' is not used.
    See |string-match| for how {pat} is used.
    And a "~" in {sub} is not replaced with the previous {sub}.
    Note that some codes in {sub} have a special meaning
    |sub-replace-special|.  For example, to replace something with
    "\n" (two characters), use "\\\\n" or '\\n'.
    When {pat} does not match in {expr}, {expr} is returned
    unmodified.
    When {flags} is "g", all matches of {pat} in {expr} are
    replaced.  Otherwise {flags} should be "".
    Example: >
        :let &path = substitute(&path, ",\\=[^,]*$", "", "")
    This removes the last component of the 'path' option. 
        :echo substitute("testing", ".*", "\\U\\0", "")
    results in "TESTING".
```

In your example I guess that
`let l:bar = substitute(l:bar, "world", "kitten", "")` should work

Comment: I am using `substitute` in my example with the buffer; though I don't know how to apply it to a variable, rather than the buffer.

Comment: @Sebasitan P. : There are 2 substitute command, if you check the first one I mention you'll get the syntax for substitute function (and not the command)

Comment: `:h substitute` gives me the same as help page as `:h :substitute`, so it's rather hard for me to see the difference.

Comment: @Sebastian P. : Sorry I got two different results with Vim 7.3. I'll expand my answer then.

Comment: You have a problem: `&l:bar` will try to get value of 'bar' option (just like `&bar`, differences will occur if you try to modify it), not `l:bar` variable.

Comment: @ZyX : Ok I have not tried myself, and it is not quite clear what the & does for me...

Comment: @Xavier T. it is explained into `:h expr-option` and `:h let-&`.

Answer (score 1):

I get tired of having to look up vim's manual to avoid magic when creating my plugin [vim-encode](https://github.com/roxma/vim-encode), here's a  pure vimscript implementation for plain text find & replace

Usage: `s:strreplace("abc","a","b")` returns `"bbc"`, `s:strreplace("abc",["a","b"],["b","a"])` returns `"bac"`

```
    func! s:strfind(s,find,start)
            if type(a:find)==1
                    let l:i = a:start
                    while l:i<len(a:s)
                            if strpart(a:s,l:i,len(a:find))==a:find
                                    return l:i
                            endif
                            let l:i+=1
                    endwhile
                    return -1
            elseif type(a:find)==3
                    " a:find is a list
                    let l:i = a:start
                    while l:i<len(a:s)
                            let l:j=0
                            while l:j<len(a:find)
                                    if strpart(a:s,l:i,len(a:find[l:j]))==a:find[l:j]
                                            return [l:i,l:j]
                                    endif
                                    let l:j+=1
                            endwhile
                            let l:i+=1
                    endwhile
                    return [-1,-1]
            endif
    endfunc

    func! s:strreplace(s,find,replace)
            if len(a:find)==0
                    return a:s
            endif
            if type(a:find)==1 && type(a:replace)==1
                    let l:ret = a:s
                    let l:i = s:strfind(l:ret,a:find,0)
                    while l:i!=-1
                            let l:ret = strpart(l:ret,0,l:i).a:replace.strpart(l:ret,l:i+len(a:find))
                            let l:i = s:strfind(l:ret,a:find,l:i+len(a:replace))
                    endwhile
                    return l:ret
            elseif  type(a:find)==3 && type(a:replace)==3 && len(a:find)==len(a:replace)
                    let l:ret = a:s
                    let [l:i,l:j] = s:strfind(l:ret,a:find,0)
                    while l:i!=-1
                            let l:ret = strpart(l:ret,0,l:i).a:replace[l:j].strpart(l:ret,l:i+len(a:find[l:j]))
                            let [l:i,l:j] = s:strfind(l:ret,a:find,l:i+len(a:replace[l:j]))
                    endwhile
                    return l:ret
            endif

    endfunc
```