# NeoVim yank inside pattern

Tags: vim, neovim

I have a code like:

```php
$class->function('passedValue');

// some code...

$myVar = $class->function('anotherPassedValue');

// more code...

$anotherVar = $class->function('yetAnotherPassedValue');
```

And I want to YANK to system memory all the values `$class->function('<HERE>');`

So, my goal is to get this in the default system clipboard:

```
passedValue
anotherPassedValue
yetAnotherPassedValue
```

I ***don't*** want to change them in any way (delete/change/replace), just copy to default system clipboard.

The Visual Block selection won't work, as they're all over the place (not aligned).

Does Nvim (or Vim) have something native for that?
I'm using 0.8 version in terminal (not GUI).
I suppose it's possible with some regex, but I can't figure out how...

Thank you all.

Comment: I do not think so. You need to copy these one by one. What is your end goal here? Seems like a [xy problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to copy matches from `:g` to register `*`:

```
:let @*='' | g/function/let @* = @* . "\n" . getline('.')
```

You need to do some further adjustments:

- change `@*` to whatever your clipboard register is
- since that command copies entire lines (with one or more matches), you'd need to [substitute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4864143/845034) the result of `getline()` or [search+replace in a register](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/15037/1769).